# SQLite create function in MediaWiki

Tags: php, regex, sqlite, mediawiki

SQLite database doesn't havea REGEXP function defined. According to its documentation (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#regexp):

> The REGEXP operator is a special syntax for the regexp() user function. No regexp() user function is defined by default and so use of the REGEXP operator will normally result in an error message. If an application-defined SQL function named "regexp" is added at run-time, then the "X REGEXP Y" operator will be implemented as a call to "regexp(Y,X)".

In PHP I can create a REGEXP function using the sqlite_create_function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-create-function.php), but when I try using this method in a MediaWiki extension I am not able to find how to call this function using MediaWiki database abstraction classes (I researched a lot but at the moment I didn't find an answer).

Is there a way to have access to this method?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classDatabaseBase.html#a76f9e6cb7b145a3d9020baebf94b499e), the `conds` parameter of the `DatabaseBase::select` function can have elements that are raw SQL fragments.

Comment: Adding raw SQL fragments will not help me with this issue, as SQLite doesn't have a regex statement built in.